# Align dates on alternate columns Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, alignment, time-series

I have a Pandas Dataframe, the columns 1-3-5-7...contain dates, the columns 2-4-6-8-.. contain data values. The dates in the columns do not correspond.
I want a single column containing all dates and the remaining columns containing just values 
Example:

```
input

      date val1       date   val2        date val3 
2007-12-01 35.6  2007-12-05 101.1  2007-12-05 89.1
2007-12-02 36.7. 2007-12-06 102.3  2007-12-07 89.3
2007-12-05 36.7  2007-12-07 108.3. 2007-12-08 89.5
2007-12-06 36.9  2007-12-08 110.0  2007-12-09 89.3
2007-12-07 36.9. 2007-12-09 102.3  2007-12-12 89.9

output

      date   val1   val2   val3 
2007-12-01   35.6     na     na 
2007-12-02   36.7     na     na 
2007-12-05   36.7  101.1   89.1 
2007-12-06   36.9  102.3     na 
2007-12-07   36.9  108.3   89.3 
2007-12-08     na  110.0   89.5
2007-12-09     na  102.3   89.3
2007-12-12     na     na   89.9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iteratively join all the couple of columns into a new empty dataframe.

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({"date": []})
N = len(df.columns)
for n in range(N // 2):
    dft = dft.merge(df.iloc[:, 2*n:2*(n+1)], on='date', how='outer')
```

Notice that  we define an empty column date to merge on it the first iteration. The `'outer'` key says that all the values coming both from the left (initial) and right (merged) dataframe are to be kept, and `nans` added where needed. Hope this helps.

Comment: the data is very big indeed, that's why I am looking for an elegant and efficient way to perform this task

Comment: If the data is larger than a few GB, maybe pyspark is a better solution?

Comment: Hi, you can check my edit. The code is now compact and runs with an arbitrarily large number of columns. Performances are quite ok: with 800 000 rows and 6 columns, it takes less than 3 seconds on my machine.

Comment: this I think is a very good solution, however I get an error after the first loop: KeyError: 'date'

Comment: The error means that you are calling the merge operation on pairs of columns that do not contain 'date'. Try to run `print(df.keys())` and check carefully what is the name of all columns that you have. You can paste the result here so we can check together.

Comment: of course!! my mistake.. I was reading from an xls file and during import pandas renamed the date columns to date.1, date.2, date.3, etc.... I fixed this with `df.columns = ['date' if x[0:4] == 'date' else x for x in list(df)]`

Comment: I have memory issues, the data frame grows very big do you know how to avoid this error? "Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)"

Comment: I can't test it now, but try to do `for n in range(N // 2): \n dft = dft.merge(df.iloc[:, 0:2], on='date', how='outer') \n df = df.iloc[:,2:]`. It will destroy the old dataframe while creating the new one and should keep the memory usage constant. `\n` just shows where to end the line.

Comment: hmmm it did not solve the problem.. the data frame has 15 years of daily data

Comment: That's definitely not my domain of expertise, but try to run `gc.collect()` inside the loop? See https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html

Comment: still not working, I keep this open, maybe someone can help.. I am now investigating dask https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You can try so(It can happen that columns with same name are renamed):

```
df:
         date   val1      date.1    val2      date.2  val3
0  2007-12-01   35.6  2007-12-05   101.1  2007-12-05  89.1
1  2007-12-02  36.7.  2007-12-06   102.3  2007-12-07  89.3
2  2007-12-05   36.7  2007-12-07  108.3.  2007-12-08  89.5
3  2007-12-06   36.9  2007-12-08   110.0  2007-12-09  89.3
4  2007-12-07  36.9.  2007-12-09   102.3  2007-12-12  89.9

for index, i in enumerate(xrange(0,len(df.columns),2)):
    col = df.columns[i]
    name = 'df' + str(index)
    name = df.iloc[:,i:i+2]
    if index == 0:
        dft = name
    name.columns = ['date', ('value' + str(i/2+1))]
    if index !=0:
        dft = dft.merge(name, on='date', how='outer')
print dft
```

Output:

```
         date value1  value2  value3
0  2007-12-01   35.6     NaN     NaN
1  2007-12-02  36.7.     NaN     NaN
2  2007-12-05   36.7   101.1    89.1
3  2007-12-06   36.9   102.3     NaN
4  2007-12-07  36.9.  108.3.    89.3
5  2007-12-08    NaN   110.0    89.5
6  2007-12-09    NaN   102.3    89.3
7  2007-12-12    NaN     NaN    89.9
```